# CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting returning null

Tags: c#, azure, app-config, azure-storage

Following instructions [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/) I have:

```
var connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString");
```

But `connectionString` is `null`, here is my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="StorageConnectionString"
         connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storage;AccountKey=key" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well this works, even if the comment doesn't fit, because I do have a ref to CloudConfigManager:

> If you are creating an application with no reference to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudConfigurationManager, and your connection string is located in the web.config or app.config as show above, then you can use ConfigurationManager to retrieve the connection string. You will need to add a reference to System.Configuration.dll to your project and add another namespace declaration for it:

```
using System.Configuration;

CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is marked correct. The question posted references CloudConfigurationManager, but this solution uses ConfigurationManager. They are NOT the same thing. Nikolai Joukov has the correct answer to the question as asked, in my opinion.

Comment: @Nathan While Nikolai's answer might explain what is wrong, it's missing any solution.

Answer (score 21):

Had the same problem.  Instead of using a connection string, use the configuration->appSettings->add key like this...

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="[ConnectionStringHere]" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: this is not the answer

Comment: It was the answer for me. I had the connection string in the Azure project settings and it suddenly stopped working for me without any explanation that I can think of (no updates to SDK or nuget packages etc). Adding the appSetting to the Web.config worked for me as well. Thanks for the help

Comment: Happy to confirm this advice still works as of July 2017. Using VS2017 (Preview 15.3) and with a freshly created blank Azure Cloud/ASP.NET WebApp .Net 4.6 the CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(..) method fetched a Web.config file setting when running locally. Following a publish to Azure from within VS2017 the same code fetched a setting value from a separate App Service setting that was declared via the Azure Portal. I changed the Azure Portal setting with a distinct value to confirm and then republished the web app from VS2017 again to ensure the Azure setting value was not overridden.

Answer (score 20):

As per documentation in MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.cloudconfigurationmanager.aspx

Only configuration settings within the appSettings tag can be read by CloudConfigurationManager. If your configuration settings are within a different tag, calling GetSetting will return Null.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. I had updated the project to use Azure SDK 2.0. I updated NuGet packages for my web and worker roles, but the Azure project in Visual Studio was still on the old version.

To fix this, Right-Click on your Azure project and select Properties. Under the Application tab, you'll see a button to Update your Azure SDK.

Comment: the button to upgrade isn't available until after you download and install the sdk (easy to do with the web platform installer)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure all your references are in synch. There's the 2012-06 library and 2012-10 Set them to Copy Local = true and verify SDK version. I dealt with the exact same thing, drove me nuts.

Comment: Did you install via NuGet? I did, and I have Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage v2.0.0.0 (.net 4.0) and Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration v1.8.0.0 (.net 3.5) Does that sound wrong?

Comment: I upgraded to the Windows Azure SDK for .NET - 2.0. After auto-upgrading the azure projects it also didn´t find the configuration strings. After manually updating all references to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration to version 2.0.0.0 (they were 1.8.0.0) it worked.

Comment: @weston sorry for the late response ... was OOtown ... did you get it all resolved?

Comment: @SocialMitch You went to Object Orientated town? That sounds better than Lego Land. I can't wait to take the kids there

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me when I upgraded the Azure SDK to version 2.2.

To fix it I changed the packages.config to use a newer version of the Azure ConfigurationManager.

```
<package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" version="2.0.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on my understanding, I'd like to point out that CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting will look into web.config if you're running out of a cloud service. It will look into cscfg if you're inside a cloud service.

Please refer this
[link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432586/azure-webrole-cloudconfigurationmanager-getsetting-returns-null/30049598#30049598)

Answer (score 3):

Following this tutorial:

You can get configuration settings like this:

```
RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("StorageConnectionString")
```

Comment: This fixed it for me. Maybe the `CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting` call doesn't look at cloud configurations any more in Azure v2.5.

Answer (score 1):

I got this after upgrading Azure SDK from 2.0 to 2.2. I was able to fix by:

1. Right-Clicking Azure project and selecting Properties. Update Azure SDK as per the Application tab. (Thanks to rattrick's answer).
2. Right click to Manage NuGet Packages. On the left click Updates and update WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (two times). 
Even after restarting Visual Studio and after restarting the Azure emulator the CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("SettingName") returns null.

I was sure that it has worked before and I had the latest SDK.

So the solutions was restarting my PC and after that CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("SettingName") returns the right value.

Comment: Restarting fixed it for me as well

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue this am after revisiting my Azure solution (Web + Worker role) to update it for `Azure 2.5`.  Reviewing the help for `CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting`, if its running under a cloud platform (Azure) it reads from the `ServiceConfiguration.csfg`, if running as a `.net` web app, reads from app or `web.config`.

So my fix was to simply change the start up project back to the Azure cloud project, not the Web project.
I was getting null because it was hosted in the wrong platform and reading from the `.config` files with no settings.
(Doh!)

Answer (score 1):

It is an old thread but I wanted to share my solution if issue is not resolved by above mentioned methods then make sure that Azure Storage Emulator is running when you run the application; at least for me this happened. For me I had to create a class to handle emulator issue as mentioned here...

> http://blog.simontimms.com/2013/08/28/configuration-settings-in-an-azure-worker-role/

```
class ConfigurationProvider
{
    private static string GetStorageConnectionString(string name)
    {
        try
        {
            return RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(name);
        }
        catch (SEHException)
        {
            return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString;
        }
    }

    public static string StorageConnectionString()
    {
        return GetStorageConnectionString("StorageConnectionString");
    }

    public static string DefaultConnection()
    {
        return GetStorageConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had quite similar problems. I updated from Azure SDK 2.0 to 2.2 - during this process I used the NuGet Manager to update the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage to the latest. The PackageManager automatically took Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration to 1.8.0.0. I was not able to get this running (it was for .Net 2.0!?). After I manually set all References to

- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage 2.1.0.0
- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration 2.0.0.0

everything worked.

I think this is because of the way CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting loads the assembly and calls the funktions (via reflection).

Answer (score 0):

Same here after upgrading Azure SDK from 2.2 to 2.3.:

Right-Click the Azure project select Properties. In the Application tab click "Upgrade..." (Thanks to rattrick's answer).

Then there was one more error to resolve:
Trying to run the Azure Project in the Compute Emulator threw an exception:
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll
Additional information:  konnte nicht erstellt werden.

In the "Error List" Window of VS2013 there was the following Warning:

Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 1635

I let VS resolve this warning and everything worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me...

```
using System.Configuration;
```

...

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. None of the advices worked for me, but the "issue" was straightforward. One simple has to understand how this class works.

It does not go into your `app.config` / `web.config` or wherever you store your application settings. `CloudConfigurationManager` works with `ServiceConfiguration.*.cscfg` and `ServiceConfiguration.csdef`. The .csdef must contain a definition of the setting, but not its value under the `ConfigurationSettings` section. The settings themselves sit in .cscfg files (under the same section but including the value; I suppose the reason for the double definition is to make sure both the cloud and the local configurations have the same settings).

You can set these either by right-clicking your role in Visual Studio and selecting Properties -> Settings (in case of StorageConnectionString, simply pick "Your subscription", if your storage account is connected to the cloud service), or by editing them manually. If you mess up the settings, you'll get an exclamation mark icon.

Simple as that.

Answer (score -2):

Was getting a null value with when passing a literal string as well after installing Azure SDK 2.6 (was working before).

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureStorage"].ConnectionString);
```

Replaced the literal string and it worked fine.

```
   string connectionStr = "AzureStorage";

   var connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStr].ConnectionString;

   CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionstring);
```