# CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting returning null After publishing

Tags: azure, azure-storage, vb.net-2010

I created a Azure project and used the below code to get the Storage ConnectionString

```
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"))
```

When i executed the project locally, it fetched the ConnectionString and i was able to successfully upload an excel file.

But after publishing the Azure project as a website, the connectionstring was returning null.

I have checked with several solutions like "Checking the version of the Azure SDK...." but everything was ok i hope...

Regards
Rajeesh

Comment: By "publishing the Azure project as a website" do you mean an azure website or a web role? Have you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/15406078/468244 ?

Comment: Yes I mean Azure Website.... I have already looked at the link you have provided.. I have updated all the versions to the latest one.

Answer (score 4):

I had quite similar problems. I updated from Azure SDK 2.0 to 2.2 - during this process I used the NuGet Manager to update the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage to the latest. The PackageManager automatically took Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration to 1.8.0.0. I was not able to get this running (it was for .Net 2.0!?). After I manually set all References to

- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage 2.1.0.0
- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration 2.0.0.0

everything worked.

I think this is because of the way CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting loads the assembly and calls the funktions (via reflection).

hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

the CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ConnectionString") refers to some values whether for local development or for the windows azure storage account.

if you are running the windows azure project locally, the project will run with no problem because you made him running locally.

if you are looking to make it running on the Cloud here are the steps you should do.
1- double click on the role you have created un the folder roles in the Windows Azure project.  this should open the properties page.
2- add setting and name it whatever you like in the code you have entered it was "ConnectionString" for the values click on the left most button of this field, a new window will pop up asking to enter more details for your Windows Azure account.
3- use of the available options whether entering the WIndows Azure storage credentials manually or if you have downloaded the publish settings just import it to the solution.

let me know if this has worked or if you need anything else.

Comment: Hello hhaggan, CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ConnectionString") refers to the Windows Azure Storage Account. I have already set those details you had mentioned... But still no luck...

Comment: When i publish to the Azure as a Cloud Service, then i get the connection string using CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString")), but not with Azure Website

Comment: Has anyone went through the same issue?

Comment: i didn't face this issue before frankly, I think you might have done something wrong during the process