# Error Publishing to Azure 2.7 in VS 2015

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-web-roles, azure-deployment

I'm trying to do an Azure deployment with two web roles in it. I'm getting the following error after it builds and at the very beginning of the deployment.

Error       CloudServices41 : The entrypoint ODataHQ.Query.dll  is not a valid assembly. Please provide a relative path to the binary that implements the entrypoint.   ODataHQ.Query.Azure C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.7\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets  1057

This error is happening on a co-workers machine as well. We just recently upgraded to Azure 2.7 inside of Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and this is the first deployment we've attempted.

Can't find anything about it on the Internet, any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384186/cloudconfigurationmanager-getsetting-returning-null)

Comment: Hari Hara Chandan that post isn't even remotely related to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out the issue. I had added another worker role to my Azure deployment project, then I wanted to remove that worker role and add a web role in its place, but keep all the settings. So I manually renamed the worker role to the name of the web role in the ServiceDefinition.csdef, but I didn't change the tag to be a web role.

```
<WorkerRole name="MyProjectName" vmsize="Small">
```

Should have been changed back to

```
<WebRole name="MyProjectName" vmsize="Small">
```