# Argument Null Exception while cloud service is on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, azure-cloud-services

I have created a cloud service, with MVC Web Role which is working fine on my Local machine, but when i host it on IIS 8, it gives an exception: 
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: connectionString 
. The lines on which it is giving the error are as follows

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("DefaultConnectionString"));
```

Its my company's project, so i won't be able to post any more lines of Code. Hope that you will understand. The method on calling which exception is raised is accessing Azure Table Storage. It is located in a class library project in the same solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you can't answer, please don't downvote atleast. Let others answer. And pls comment with a reason if you are downvoting

Comment: Could `CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("DefaultConnectionString")` simply return `null`? Did you set all settings?

Comment: @PatrickHofman yes it is simply returning null, but only when it is on IIS. Its working perfectly on local machine

Comment: So, did you set all settings?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/15384186/993547.

Comment: @PatrickHofman yes i have set the value of connection string to use the intended blob. And ok i realize that its duplicate, but it didn't turn up in suggestions when i was typing. Due to low repo, i am not able to comment in anyone's post, and over that if you will downvote, it will be worse. Pls upvote if you find my concern genuine

Comment: Strop trying to influence the voting of users. If I find your post useful, I will vote accordingly.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I am not trying to get vote. I was saying that if you could just reverse the downvote.

Comment: Why do you think I downvoted? Why do you think the only guy that is helping you is downvoting you?

Comment: @PatrickHofman ok. You gave the link to duplicate post, so i thought that you were giving the reason of downvoting. And i am thankful to you that you are giving your precious time to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the value in your project's app.config file (look in the solution explorer for the file). It should be in the  section and be something like:

`<add key="DefaultConnectionString" value="some_long_string">`

Azure uses different values for local testing and deployment to the cloud, for deployment you need the value that belongs to your company's Azure Storage account.

Or try

`using System.Configuration;
...
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString);` to read the value from app.config without using the CloudConfigurationManager.

Comment: Secret Squirrel. The last part of your answer helped me.

Comment: All that the getSetting method does is read the value depending on how the project is set up. Setting up cloud services is complicated, but if just GetSetting is returning null then it just means it can't find the value locally.